# Sending multiple emails from dataframe values

Tags: python, sql, dataframe, csv, email

First-timer here!  My Python code is supposed to run an SQL query, write the results to a CSV, convert the CSV to a dataframe and use values in the dataframe to compose and send an email.  The email addresses are a list in the dataframe, and delimited by a comma.

```
first_name  middle_name  last_name    email                           pref_lang  exp_date      p_id
Joe         A            Smith        jas@gmail.com                   eng        Aug 22, 2022  001
NaN         NaN          Joe A Smith  jas@business.org                cht        Dec 03, 2030  002
NaN         NaN          Joe A Smith  jas@gmail.com,jas@business.org  eng        Oct 16, 2024  003
```

Everything works ok but the emails are only being sent to the first address in the list.  The second address appears in the "to" when the email is received but mailtraces on the SMTP server fail to find any email sent to the second address.

I've searched high and low on this site and others for a similar issue and can't find a solution.  What should I do differently to send the email to multiple addresses in the same row?

```
import psycopg2
import csv
import pandas
import itertools
import operator
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.utils import formatdate
from email import encoders
from datetime import date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='' user='' host='' port='' password='' sslmode=''")
except psycopg2.Error as e:
    print ("Unable to connect to database: " + str(e))

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(open("query.sql","r").read())

key_func = operator.itemgetter(0, 1)

with open('file.csv', mode='w', newline='') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow([ i[0] for i in cursor.description ])
    writer.writerows(cursor.fetchall())

conn.close()

df = pandas.read_csv('file.csv')

def sendemail(html, to_email):
    emailhost = ''
    emailport = ''
    emailfrom= ''
    emailsubject = 'Subject'
    emailto = [str(row[3])]
    text = '''Dear {} {} {}, somethng happened and I want to tell you about it: {}. Thank You.'''.format(str(row[0]),str(row[1]),str(row[2]),str(row[5]))
    smtp = smtplib.SMTP(emailhost, emailport)
    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    part1 = MIMEText(text,'plain')
    msg['From'] = emailfrom
    if type(emailto) is list:
        msg['To'] = ', '.join(emailto)
    else:
        msg['To'] = emailto
    msg['Date'] = formatdate(localtime = True)
    msg['Subject'] = emailsubject
    msg.attach (part1)
    server = smtplib.SMTP(emailhost, emailport)
    server.sendmail(emailfrom, emailto, msg.as_string())
    server.quit()

for row in df.itertuples(index=False):
    sendemail(df.to_html(index=False), df['email'])
```

Comment: Your send email is hard coded 'emailto = [str(row[3])]'

Comment: Thanks for the comment!  Do you have any suggestions on how to change the definition of that variable?